# Why is the volume of this tetrahedron 1/6 times the product of side lengths?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, optimization

Given an ellipsoid $$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1$$

And bounding a volume that is a tetrahedron with 4 planes, the $x=y=z=0$ planes and the plane tangent to the ellipsoid at some point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, why is the volume of this tetrahedron

$$ \frac {1}{6} \frac {a^2b^2c^2}{x_0y_0z_0} $$

Can someone please offer some intuition on how this formula is derived?  Wikipedia, Wolfram and other problems that I have looked up regarding volumes of tetrahedron have not helped much.

Is $\large \frac {a^2}{x_0}$ the "length" of a side of the tetrahedron?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's find the volume of an easier tetrahedron, namely a tetrahedron found from the planes $x=y=z=0$ and $Ax+By+Cz=D$. It is nothing but $\frac{1}{6}\frac{D}{A}\frac{D}{B}\frac{D}{C}$, where $\frac{D}{A}$ etc are the lengths of the sides.

Now back to your example we only need to find the tangent plane at $x_0,y_0,z_0$ on the ellipsoid. Since the ellipsoid is given as a contour equation:
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1
$$
The gradient of $f$ is normal to the ellipsiod at any point, in particular $\mathbf{n}=\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \frac{2x_0}{a^2}\hat{x}+\frac{2y_0}{b^2}\hat{y}+\frac{2z_0}{c^2}\hat{z}$ is the normal vector for the tangent plane at $\mathbf{v}_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on the ellipsoid. The plane is given simply as $\mathbf{n}\cdot (\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v}_0)=0$ or
$$
0=\frac{x_0(x-x_0)}{a^2}+\frac{y_0(y-y_0)}{b^2}+\frac{z_0(z-z_0)}{c^2}
$$
which can be rewritten as (using the ellipsoid equation)
$$
\left(\frac{x_0}{a^2}\right)x+\left(\frac{y_0}{b^2}\right)y+\left(\frac{z_0}{c^2}\right)z = 1
$$
Now by what we found in the beginning the volume is simply
$$V=\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{6x_0y_0z_0}$$
and yes $\frac{a^2}{x_0}$ is the sidelength.

Comment: Hi @Hamed, I think I needed more work on this, so I instead went a step further back.  And I worked out that the volume of a pyramid in the first octant is 1/6 (abc), by writing some simple line equations, and integrating right triangles over the height z.  So, a single-variable integral over z, gives me 1/6(abc), which I believe should be the volume  of this pyramid.  Now, is this pyramid exactly a "tetrahedron"?  So that the volume I have computed is exactly the volume of a tetrahedron in the first octant?

Comment: And if I have now understood this much, and also know the tangent plane to the ellipsoid, how do I use this last piece of information to get your $V$ formula?  I have in mind this question: why is a side now instead of "a" that I started with, $a^2/x_0$?  Thanks @Hamed

Comment: It might just be a simple interpretation of the tangent plane to the ellipsoid, perhaps, e.g., the sides of the pyramid are now (instead of a,b,c) the coefficients of the tangent plane equation - but inverted, it seems like.  Is this sort of the algorithm to remember?  Or, should I follow some more intuition that I don't seem to have yet?  Thanks @Hamed

Comment: Oh, I think I got it @Hamed -- the side lengths are just simply solving for x, y and z in the tangent plane equation ... setting y=z=0, x=y=0, and x=z=0 ...

Comment: If you wouldn't mind answering just one last question: is the pyramid ... used interchangeably with "tetrahedron"?  Or, are they different objects?  Thanks @Hamed

Comment: Pyramid can have any shape as its base (the great pyramid for example has a square base) tetrahedron is special case of pyramid in which all bases are all triangles

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for your help @Hamed.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Also for further intuition I suggest you think about a simpler problem: the area of a triangle resulting from intersection of x axis y axis and a tangent line to a circle at a point. Draw it to see everything concretely

Comment: Ok, will do @Hamed -- thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @Hamed, I am back for one last question, if you don't mind:  the motivation to learn how to derive the volume of the tetrahedron was so that I can minimize this volume, using the ellipsoid given as the constraint.  In doing so, I find only one critical point, and evaluating it gives a function value of $$V= \frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}|abc|$$.  But, how do I know that this value must be a minimum volume (in the first octant)?  Is there something to observe right away that answers the question, or should I proceed with *unconstrained techniques*, i.e., check the Hessian matrix?  Thanks,

Comment: Oh I see... If you want to be rigorous yes Hessian is the way to go, BUT you can do a simple observation. You see if you choose your point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ along any of the axis in the first octant the volume becomes infinite (why?) So any critical point must necessarily be a minimum.